# How to approximate a f(t) in terms of t when f(t) is a function of itself?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, approximation

So I have a function

$f(x)=\left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       1, & x = 0 \\
       3 + f(x/2), & x = even \\
       3 + f((x-1)/2), & x = odd
     \end{array}
   \right.$

and I can see from graphing it, that it is approximately:

$f(x)=3\log_{2}(x) + 4$

where x > 0

what method(s) can I use to find this solution? Some kind of correlation? or is there an algebraic solution? or something else?

Problem source, incase I missed something:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ud3oeInn_8c

Comment: ok so I worked this out. So I pulled out of the air that f'(x) = a/x  , then from that f(x) = a * ln(x)  , substituting this into the even condition gives, a* ln(a)=3 + a*ln(x/2) .... a = 3/ln(2)..... for x = 1 odd condition 3+(f(0)) = 3* ln(1) /ln(2) +c ..... 4 = c ..... f(x) = 3 log(x)/log(2) +4 for even numbers.

Comment: Try to prove that for all $2^n\le x<2^{n+1}$ you get recursion depth $n+1$ and thus $f(x)=1+3(n+1)=4+3n=4+3\lfloor\ln_2(x)\rfloor$.